# std::make_shared makes two constructor calls in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, constructor

I wrote a simple piece of code to try out make_shared for C++11.  I didn't understand why when I call:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> x = std::make_shared<MyClass>(MyClass());
```

The default constructor is called and a move constructor is called.  This seems fine at first, as the move constructor would not create a copy.  But if I comment out the implementation of the move constructor for MyClass, it would call the default constructor, followed by the copy constructor, which seems to defeat the purpose of make_shared.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

//-----------------------------------------------------------

class MyClass {

public:

    // default constructor
    MyClass() :
            _data(0.0) 
    {
            _data = (float)3.14;

            std::cout << "MyClass::default constructor - data=" << _data << " ; class=" << this << std::endl;
    };

    // copy constructor
    MyClass(const MyClass& input)
    {
            _data = input._data;

            std::cout << "MyClass::copy constructor - data=" << _data << " ; class=" << this << std::endl;
    };

    // move constructor
    MyClass(MyClass&& other)
    {
            std::cout << "MyClass::move constructor(before) - data=" << _data << " ; class=" << this << std::endl;

            _swap(*this, other);

            std::cout << "MyClass::move constructor(after) - data=" << _data << " ; class=" << this << std::endl;
    };

    // destructor
    ~MyClass()
    {
            std::cout << "MyClass::destructor - data=" << _data << " ; class=" << this << std::endl;
    };

private:

    // swap
    void MyClass::_swap(MyClass& X, MyClass& Y)
    {
            std::swap(X._data,      Y._data);
    }

    // members
    float       _data;

};

//-----------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> x = std::make_shared<MyClass>(MyClass());

    std::cout << std::endl << "Address for x: " << x << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Press Enter to exit." << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the above code is:

```
MyClass::default constructor - data=3.14 ; class=000000000019F860
MyClass::move constructor(before) - data=0 ; class=00000000003C3440
MyClass::move constructor(after) - data=3.14 ; class=00000000003C3440
MyClass::destructor - data=0 ; class=000000000019F860

Address for x: 00000000003C3440

Press Enter to exit.

MyClass::destructor - data=3.14 ; class=00000000003C3440
```

If I comment out the move constructor, the output is this:

```
MyClass::default constructor - data=3.14 ; class=000000000016FA00
MyClass::copy constructor - data=3.14 ; class=00000000001B3440
MyClass::destructor - data=3.14 ; class=000000000016FA00

Address for x: 00000000001B3440

Press Enter to exit.

MyClass::destructor - data=3.14 ; class=00000000001B3440
```

Maybe there's a flaw to my understanding of what make_shared does.  Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Its seesm straight-forward -- `make_shared` needs to copy/move the unnamed `MyClass()` temp you created explicitly into the shared object space it allocates.  It uses the move constructor if it can, or the copy constructor if there is no move constructor.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I actually wanted to do (in my mind) what Piotr S. suggested so it only does a single constructor call.  I didn't fully understand the syntax for make_shared.  Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> x = std::make_shared<MyClass>(MyClass());
```

this is what happens:

1. The inner `MyClass()` instance is created (the **first constructor call - a default one**).
2. The inner `MyClass()` is a temporary.
3. Now, `make_shared` perfect-forwards your temporary `MyClass` to the *move constructor* of `MyClass`, because `MyClass` declares one and temporaries can be bound by rvalue references `MyClass&&`. (the **second constructor call - move constructor**).

Now, when you remove the move-constructor, this is what happens:

1. The inner `MyClass()` instance is created (the **first constructor call - a default one**).
2. The inner `MyClass()` is a temporary.
3. Now, `make_shared` perfect-forwards your temporary `MyClass`, but because `MyClass` does not have a move constructor, instead the temporary is bound by the `const MyClass&` reference of a copy constructor, and so the copy constructor is invoked (the **second constructor call - the copy constructor**).

That is, arguments you pass to `std::make_shared` are actually the **constructor's arguments** rather than the instance itself. Hence you should write:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> x = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
```

If for instance you had a `MyClass` constructor of the following signature:

```
MyClass(int x, float f, std::unique_ptr<int> p);
```

then you would say:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> x
        = std::make_shared<MyClass>(123, 3.14f, std::make_unique<int>(5));
```

And `make_shared` guarantees those arguments will be *perfectly-forwarded* to `MyClass` constructor.

You can think of the `std::make_shared` helper function as the one that looks as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_shared(Args&&... args) -> std::shared_ptr<T>
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

*NOTE: In reality `make_shared` also allocates space for a reference counter in a continuous memory block, binds a destructor, and does other magic. The above snippet is just an example to illustrate what happens with the arguments themselves.*

Comment: Your suggestion is what I actually need to do.  Thank you for this detailed response!

Answer (score 3):

Just use this:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> x = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
```

That way, no temporary is created.

`std::make_shared<X>(args...)` passes args... to the `X` constructor for the object it is creating.  In your case, you want no arguments passed to the constructor.

If you pass `MyClass()`, then you are creating a default-constructed object, and then passing that as an argument to the object that is being created.  It is as if you did this:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> x(new MyClass(MyClass()));
```

which is unnecessary.